# Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

me está saliendo un Warning que no debería aparecerme cuando ejecuto el siguiente código,

```
    <?php
    function mysqlSanitizer($data)
    {
        $data= mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data);
        $data= stripslashes($data);
        return $data;
    }
    if(isset($_POST["register"])){

    if(!empty($_POST['full_name']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['username']) &&                 !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $full_name=$_POST['full_name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $username_sanitized=mysqlSanitizer($username);
    $password_sanitized=mysqlSanitizer($password);

    $query=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='".$username_sanitized."'");
    //$query=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='".$username."'");
    $numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

He leído varias preguntas y en casi todas comentan que el problema es la conexión en mi caso la variable $link, pero no es mi caso, porque esto ya funcionaba sin añadir la nueva función

```
    mysqlSanitizer
```

He revisado https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php y parece que lo tengo todo correcto, de hecho estos Warning no me impiden registrar un nuevo usuario, pero al revisar la base de datos no guarda ni el nombre ni la contraseña del mismo

¿Alguien sabe por qué puede estar pasando esto?

Gracias,
Saludos!

Comment: PEro entonces no deberias ver el codigo que usas para guardar usuarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La variable `$link` esta definida fuera del contexto (`scope`) de la función `mysqlSanitizer`

#### Soluciones:

- **OPCIÓN 1:**
  Pasando la variable `$link` como parámetro:

  ```
    function mysqlSanitizer($link, $data)
    {
        $data= mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data);
        $data= stripslashes($data);
        return $data;
    }

    // Ejemplo de uso
    $username_sanitized=mysqlSanitizer($link, $username);
  ```
- **OPCIÓN 2**:

  Definir la variable `$link` como [`global`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) dentro de la función:

  ```
    function mysqlSanitizer($data)
    {
        global $link;

        $data= mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$data);
        $data= stripslashes($data);
        return $data;
    }

    // Ejemplo de uso
    $username_sanitized=mysqlSanitizer($username);
  ```

---

Referencias:

- [Ámbito de las variables - Manual PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Gracias, totalmente cierto, no tenía dicha variable al alcance en la función. De nuevo gracias Marcos